# IMAGE Function not displaying image in field (previously worked)

Tags: custom-field, formula-field, image-formula, standardlayout

I have a formula field that makes use of IMAGE function to show an image from a url.  It goes like this:

HYPERLINK(URL__c , 
IMAGE( URL__c , "Photo unavailable", 400, 400))

The image itself doesn't show in Salesforce.com page but clicking the image navigates to the page outside of SF showing the image.  The actual image used to show the image on the SF page (btw this is on a Standard page layout, not VF or Apex).  So I can assume the link is correct if I'm navigated there when I click.

The URL__c field is a dynamic formula field that creates the URL based on the record selected.

Why would this all of a sudden not work?  I.E. Why did it stop showing me the image in SF page layout for the selected record?  This is something that has been working in production for over a year.

This is what show in Production:
[image]

This is what shows in sandbox.
[image]

Formulas in Prod and Sandbox are identical.  URL__c are built exactly the same.

Comment: Where is it happening? Sandbox? Does anybody enable the Hyperlink critical update? Do you see and error in browser console/developer tool?

Comment: Oddly enough this is happening in Prod.  Sandbox the image shows.

Comment: Is the URL also pointing to same image at same location?

Comment: You have mentioned, "Formulas in Prod and Sandbox are identical". Is it same or identical? If possible please provide both the URLs.

Comment: @SarojBera  yes the url is pointing to the same image in the same location.  The formula in prod is identical to the formula in sandbox.  This is something that has be in production and working for over a year but all of a sudden the production org has stopped showing the image.

Comment: Consequently...It appears to be working again today in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working now.  Not sure why.  Not sure why it stopped though so....